# How to increase junit viewer font size in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am trying to increase the Junit view font size as shown in the image.

[image]

I tried to find the solution but my bad luck that I failed. Hopefully I will get some help soon.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. JUnit View fonts are most probably hardcoded.